# How to add classes for each piece of text pulled by Ajax from another site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i'm pulling data from my wordpress site, to my mobile site (different sites).

Wordpress = php and mobile site = static html.

Obviously i want the same content in both sites, because it is the 'same'.

I've got to pull the data and display in HTML, now I need to manipulate that data, add classes, take chunks of text, is this possible?

My code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var pageName;
var content;

$('li a').on('click', function (){
    pageName = $(this).attr('url');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://mywebsite.com/' + pageName + '/?json=1',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            content = data.page.content;

            if (data.page.url === 'http://mywebsite.com/about/') {
                $('.testing').html(content);
            }
            else {
                $('.testing').html('nothing to do');
            }

        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
});
```

I'm only accepting texts from my page "about" for now.

Now, I need to take off some things, for example:

There is a text in my about pages in the wordpress site:

"

Hi, my name it's Marcelo, i love girls

"

And i want display in the mobile app this:

"Hi, my name it's Marcelo, i love"

Or maybe adding a Class or a ID to use differently..

I don't know how manipulate the texts, titles, and images..

Any help is welcome.

Comment: why aren't you using the same php version on mobile?

Comment: because the company needs to generate profits, and we were losing sales because of the lack of a version for phones and tablets. 

We decided to create a mobile version with jquery mobile because it takes little time to develop (2 days).. when i finish this i will create a new site that will be responsive

Answer (score 0):

So the content is in the json p data format. What you need to do is instead of just appending it like you have done onto the testing class, you need to iterate over it and add to to the class testing or wherever and as you are adding, you can use the addClass() function to give the content the classes you need.

To manipulate text is a simple matter of using build in JavaScript functions that deal with text. Put up a more detailed structure that you want and someone will do the exact thing you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a variation on this:

```
$('li a').on('click', function (){
  $('.testing').load( $(this).attr('url') ).addClass('mobile');
});
```

This loads the entire contents of the URL into a DIV and adds a class of mobile to it.
If all the content was inside a specific ID in the HTML you could load it like this:

```
$('.testing').load( $(this).attr('url')+' #contentDiv' ).addClass('mobile');
```

Comment: i'm thinking here.. what if i add the classes in the wordpress? that way, the data will be pull with the classes.. do you thinks this is a good idea?

Comment: That should work. Without seeing everything I can't be 100% sure though.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer.  Glad to know it worked!